# React navigation v 2x setting default params into screen

Tags: react-native

I wanted to use screenProps. As it is shown below at the beginning I set up `screenProps` and use it inside of NavigationProps class by 'this.props.screenProps.cats[0].id'. But It didn't help me. Help me please if anyone knows. Appreciations in advance!

Calling NavigationDrawer class with setting `screenProps`

```
  <NavigationDrawer screenProps = {{cats:this.state.cat_list}}/>
```

Inside of NavigationDrawer class

```
const app = createStackNavigator({

            FromMainScreenToSubCats:{
            screen:FromMainScreenToSubCats,
            params: { catId:this.props.screenProps.cats[0].id  }
            },

})
```